# Is there a more optimal Linear Programming algorithm for multi-constraint binary problems?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a set of (≥200) magic the gathering cards, and I want to pick 100 of them, uniquely (e.g the cards are either selected or not). I have given the full set scores in ~ten different categories, which I'm trying to maximize...

I'm loosely familiar with the branch and bound and integer approaches, but I'm not sure if there is a more efficient approach for this case (binary, multi-constraint)

Comment: What is the objective, and what are the constraints besides picking 100 cards?

Comment: @RobPratt I've just edited to add a line, that explains my objective to maximize the categories. The contraints are just 100 cards, and uniqueness (no more than one of each card)

Comment: sounds like a multiobjective problem, how will you balance the scores between different categories?

Comment: @LinAlg not sure. I've been using a JavaScript library, and I was thinking I needed to tweak my constraints in a mathematically informed way, but I looks like I just needed to set a tolerance in the options. I'm still interested in answers but it's not as urgent now

Comment: @linAlg I dug round the library I play to use and it just uses the midpoint of each vector?